# Why is $[\widetilde{v},\widetilde{w}]_p(f)=0$ when $f$ has a critical point at $p$?

Tags: differential-geometry, morse-theory

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $f$ a smooth function $M\to\mathbb{R}$.  Let $p$ be a critical point of $f$.  We define the Hessian of $f$ at $p$ to be the symmetric bilinear functional $f_{**}$ on $T_p M$ given by $f_{**}(v,w)=\widetilde{v}_p(\widetilde{w}(f))$ where $\widetilde{v}$ and $\widetilde{w}$ are extensions of $v$ and $w$ to vector fields on $M$.  It must be checked that $f_{**}$ is symmetric and well defined.

Milnor states that $f_{**}$ is symmetric because $\widetilde{v}_p(\widetilde{w}(f)) - \widetilde{w}_p(\widetilde{v}(f)) = [\widetilde{v},\widetilde{w}]_p(f)$ where $[\widetilde{v},\widetilde{w}]$ denotes the Poisson bracket, which he says satisfies $[\widetilde{v},\widetilde{w}]_p(f)=0$ because $f$ has a critical point at $p$.  Thus since $\widetilde{v}_p(\widetilde{w}(f))$ is independent of the extension of $v$ and $\widetilde{w}_p(\widetilde{v}(f))$ is independent of the extension of $w$ we have that $f_{**}$ is well defined and symmetric by the preceding.

My confusion is why $[\widetilde{v},\widetilde{w}]_p(f)=0$.  I'm not familiar with Poisson bracket but this looks like the Lie bracket to me, not the Poisson bracket.  I'm also not sure why it is zero when evaluated at $p,f$.

Also one more (non essential) question out of curiosity, can we only define the Hessian in a coordinate free way at points where a function has a critical point?  This would seem strange to me.

Comment: because [v,w] is a vector field given that v, w are vector fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct that $[\tilde{v}, \tilde{w}]$ is the Lie bracket of vector fields. $[\tilde{v},\tilde{w}]_p(f) = 0$ since
$$[\tilde{v},\tilde{w}]_p(f) = df_p([\tilde{v},\tilde{w}]) = 0,$$
as $p$ is a critical point of $f$.

This definition of the Hessian only makes sense at critical points. One way to get a coordinate-free definition of the Hessian everywhere on the manifold is to choose a Riemannian metric (so that we get the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla^{LC}$) and define
$$\mathrm{Hess}(f)(X,Y) = (\nabla^{LC} df)(X,Y).$$
This definition depends on the choice of Riemannian metric, however. Nevertheless, one can show that at a critical point, it is equivalent to the definition from Milnor's book.

Comment: Ah, I see.  So I guess this should have been obvious - basically we are saying that differentiating $f$ in the direction of $[\widetilde{v},\widetilde{w}]_p$ at $p$ is zero because the total derivative of $f$ is zero.  This actually crossed by mind but then I got confused about why $\widetilde{w}(f)$ wouldn't just be zero and hence $\widetilde{v}_p\widetilde{w}(f)$.  But I guess this is because $f$ has a critical point only at $p$ so $\widetilde{w}(f)$ is not actually the zero function, it is only zero at $p$. So differentiating gives something nonzero in general.  Thanks!

Comment: @Seth can you or someone else explain me why $df_p([v,w])=0$ holds if $p$ is a critical point of $f$?

Comment: @Marc $[\tilde{v},\tilde{w}]$ is a vector field, and $[\tilde{v},\tilde{w}]_p(f)$ means to differentiate $f$ at $p$ in the direction of $[\tilde{v},\tilde{w}]_p$.  Since $p$ is a critical point of $f$, the total derivative of $f$ is zero at $p$, and hence every directional derivative is zero as well.

Comment: We use the following definition: $p\in M$ is a critical point of $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb R$ if $d(f\circ x^{-1})x(p)=0$ for some chart $x$ around $p$. Is this the same thing as "the total derivative of $f$ is zero at $p$"?

Answer (score 0):

Here I think is a complete answer to why [̃,̃]() = 0:  It is easy to check that the actions of ̃ and ̃  are derivations implies that the action of [̃,̃] is also a derivation (a linear functional which satisfies the product rule of elementary calculus).  Since all derivations are the action of some vector field (http://www.math.toronto.edu/mgualt/courses/17-1300/docs/17-1300-notes-12.pdf Theorem 4.15) the action of [̃,̃] is also that of a vector field.  Seth's remark of Jan. 11, 2016 now applies.